# Optimizing Magento url rewrites

Tags: mysql, performance, magento, http

So as I understood if you change URL of something in Magento, an entry in `core_url_rewrite` table is created which redirects new url to previous url. Each time the URL is changed, rewrites are appended, not replaced. If URL of something is changed 100 times, there will be 100 chained rewrites in `core_url_rewrite`.

First of all correct me if I'm wrong please. Secondly, what problems would there be if all links in the middle of all redirect chains were removed, leaving only the first link and the last link? Has anyone done it, was it worth it, were you using any existing scripts and what were the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At point of `100 times,.....be 100 chained rewrites in core_url_rewrite.` ,you want rewrite.

You changed the URL key of a catalog/product and ticked the box Create Permanent Redirect for old URL. Assumed you changed the URL key from my-old-product-name to my-new-product-name. Then, when this box is ticked, a rewrite from `my-old-product-name.html` to `my-new-product-name.html` will be created in the `core_url_rewrite` table. If you truncate the table, this rewrite will be gone, so that your old product URL will not work any more.It will create issue in Seo if old url  have crawled in Google

Answer (score 0):

Truncate the table and run url rewrite function using mange to admin - system again. This should overwrite all previous urls. This is what I follow for my store, and if you have huge catalog then better using putty client to rewrite the same or see if you have good memory provided by your server provider. Thanks